# Why is my texture skewed?

Tags: unity, textures, vertex, uv-mapping

I'm creating hexagonal prisms from code and am having a difficult time understanding how UV mapping works, as the texture I apply to the hexagonal face comes out skewed:

[image]

Forgetting the sides for now, here is how I'm creating the hexagonal face:

```
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f)); // N
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 0.5f * (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2), y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f / 2)); // NE
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x + 0.5f * (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2), y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f / 2)); // SE
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f)); // S
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 0.5f * (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2), y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f / 2)); // SW
    meshData.vertices.Add(new Vector3(x - 0.5f * (Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2), y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f / 2)); // NW
```

This creates a regular hexagon. My texture is also a regular hexagon. So why does it get textured at an angle?

Here is my UV code:

```
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(0.5f, 1));
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(1, 0.75f));
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(1, 0.25f));
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(0.5f, 0));
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(0, 0.25f));
    meshData.uv.Add(new Vector2(0, 0.75f));
```

Comment: When you create procedural meshes, you don't just need to set up the vertices but also [the UV coordinates](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv.html).

Comment: Oops, forgot to paste those in. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I misspoke--my hexagon texture was not, in fact, regular. I create most of my 2D programmer art in PowerPoint and mistakenly assumed that holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while drawing a hexagon would make it regular. It turns out that this only creates an arbitrarily shaped six-sided polygon that scales proportionally.

Anyone who happens to be seeking a method for producing regular hexagons in PowerPoint can utilize [the solution I found on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/890494/how-can-i-create-a-regular-hexagon-using-powerpoint)